# Edit LaTeX generated PDF file

Tags: pdf, overleaf

I just created a resume in Overleaf using LaTeX and saved it as a PDF. The tex file was somehow deleted from my Overleaf account and now I want to make some edits. Is there a way I can make changes in LaTeX to my pdf file?

Comment: basically no, you need to recover the source from a backup, or if you just have the pdf you may be able to cut and paste the text but will need to add the latex markup again by hand.

Comment: You can extract the (unformatted) text with the command **pdftotext**.

Comment: Honestly not really, the answers seem very dated.

Answer (score -1):

I give you something that can help you in this situation and more. Install Mathpix Snip

https://mathpix.com/

and see any tutorial, it's very easy actually.